# Cloning a section with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I try to clone a section after another section on user input (clicking a radio button), but it doesn’t works... 
your help is appreciated.

```
<section class="clonetester">
    <input id="1a" type="radio" value="1" name="q1">yes
    <input id="1b" type="radio" value="0" name="q1" >no
    <br />
    <input id="date1" type="datetime-local" name="date" />date<br />
</section>

<section class="here">clone follows</section>

<script>
$('input').click(function(e){
    $('#1a').(':checked'){
        $('.clonetester').clone().appendTo(".here");
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple changes that you will have to make for it to work.

- Use `change` instead of `click` for input elements.
- `$('#1a').(':checked')` has to be replaced with `$('#1a').is(':checked')` and should be enclosed in a `if` block.

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('1a') && $this.is(':checked')) {
      // closeset clonetester

      var $clonetester = $this.closest('.clonetester').first();

      if ($clonetester) {
        $clonetester.clone().appendTo(".here");
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="clonetester">
  <input class="1a" type="radio" value="1" name="q1">yes
  <input class="1b" type="radio" value="0" name="q1">no
  <br />
  <input class="date1" type="datetime-local" name="date" />date
  <br />
</section>
<section class="here">clone follows</section>
```

Comment: What id and class have the resulted clones?

Comment: It will have the exact same `class` and `id`. And since the `id` in a page has to be unique, this will break the behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to change the clone ids, like adding a number or something?

Comment: You can use a `class` instead and modify the code as the edited post above.

Comment: it works, but how do I know what id have the cloned section and elements? I need to include the “date” fields in further calculations...

Comment: it seems that “clone” is not the function I need... thanks for your help!